# Excel 2016 restart itself when I try recording a macro

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I wanted to make a **Macro** in Excel 2016 (under Win 10). I chose the **"Record Macro"** button. After opening the floating window and making a name for the macro, I click on the **"OK"** button. After that, the Excel goes to hang mode.
on the other hand, the button **"Use Relative Reference"** in Developer menu does not work and **it's highlight always**.
Shortly, I can not make a Macro in Excel 2016 under Win 10, any advice is appreciated.
Thanks Guys ...

Comment: What does "Hanging" mean here. Does it gray out and you can't click on anything and the only option is to close it, or force close through task manager? Or something else? Also.. this might be better suited for superuser.com as it's not programming related.

Comment: @JNevill
Yes, I can't click on anything and Excel restart itself after two three seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue! ... I did a click on the **"Reference ..."** in VBA Developer in Excel and I get this message: **Unrecognised Project Language** then I went to the **Regional Setting** and I cleaned up (uncheck) the Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 ... Now the VBA work correctly.